# File Not Found exception in .NET application when calling into C++/CLI DLL

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll, c++-cli

I've got a simple .NET application written in C#, which links with a C++/CLI DLL
which is itself just a thin wrapper around a C++ static library.

The app runs fine on the development machine (Windows 8), but, when the EXE and
DLL are copied over to another machine (Windows 10) it crashes immediately on
startup.

Looking in Event Viewer, I can see that the crash is due to an unhandled
exception, `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, and the call-stack indicates that
the exception occurs in a function that makes a call into the DLL.

If I edit the function in the DLL to return immediately, then the crash still
occurs. Adding a `try-catch` block around the call also has no effect. However,
if I remove the call entirely, then the application runs.

The app runs fine on the development box, even if I move the EXE and DLL to a
different location. However, if I delete the DLL from the directory in which the
EXE is located, then exactly the same crash occurs.

This suggests that the problem is that the app cannot find the DLL when run on
the other machine.

The projects for both the application and the DLL are included in the same
Visual Studio 2015 solution, and the application is linked to the DLL via a
project reference.

The application targets .NET 4.5.2, and the other machine has .NET 4.6
installed. The only other references in the application project are to parts of
.NET, such as `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System.Core`.

How can I fix this crash?

**EDIT:** As suggested by [@Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495717/crash-in-net-application-when-calling-into-c-cli-dll#comment60605390_36495717) in the comments, I tried logging bind failures with `fuslogvw.exe`, which garnered the following log excerpt:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (08/04/2016 @ 14:47:02) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  D:\[Path]\[App Name].exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = [DLL Name], Version=1.0.5941.28221, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/[Path]/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = [App Name].exe
Calling assembly : [App Name], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/[Path]/[DLL Name].DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/[Path]/[DLL Name]/[DLL Name].DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/[Path]/[DLL Name].EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/[Path]/[DLL Name]/[DLL Name].EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

So it seems that the file that cannot be found *is* my DLL, and that .NET is
indeed looking in the correct location for the file, but for some reason it is
not finding it there.

Note that I obtained the same error log on my development machine when I attempted to run the EXE with the DLL deleted.

Comment: First you should understand which file is missing. Did you deployed and installed VC++ runtime DLLs?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I installed this, which hasn't helped: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51682

Comment: Perhaps use sysinternals process monitor to observe the file system calls in realtime. (fuslogvw.exe for runtime assembly binding details)

Comment: @AlexK. I've added the output of `fuslogvw.exe` to the question.

Comment: Fuslogvw.exe only shows loading failures for .NET assemblies.  If you are sure that D:/[Path]/[DLL Name].DLL is present then the most likely failure mode is that what is missing is a DLL that it needs.  Likely to be an unmanaged DLL if this is a C++/CLI assembly.  Like one of the C++ runtime DLLs or whatever native C++ code you wrapped.  The Process Monitor trace should show the program searching for that DLL and not finding it.  Enabling loader snaps and a debugger is another way to see it.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, thanks for the info. I'll look into Process Monitor next. (I've never used it before.)

Comment: Issue mysteriously disappeared over the weekend. My best guess is that the redistributable installer actually required a reboot, although it didn't prompt for one. Thanks to all all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I tried installing the [Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51682). This didn't appear to have any effect at the time. However, a couple of days later, the problem is no longer reproducible, and I can't think of anything else that would have fixed it. (The Redistributable installer didn't request a reboot, but my best guess is that one was actually required.)